# I don't think this question should have been deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The question mentioned is not offensive or incorrect as far as I can tell and shouldn't be deleted, even if being closed was the correct action (although even that seems wrong to me).

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82559/85-code-coverage-yet-upload-fails

https://web.archive.org/web/20150910194953/http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82559/85-code-coverage-yet-upload-fails

It is also linked from the Salesforce Forum which is where I found it and had to look in wayback machine to find the content.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000IAbLQAW

Answer (score 1):

My reasoning was, that user hadn't logged in for 5 years (2 more now) and is therefore exceedingly unlikely to ever accept or even read any further answers on the post. Additionally, it didn't have any answers with positive votes, nor was it receiving much traffic. The above are not valid reasons to close a post, but seem like acceptable criteria to deem it junk. Deleting junk improves the signal to noise ratio, and getting rid of posts that continually push content off the front page due to pings by the Community bot seems like a way we can improve this site as mods.

Comment: Hmm. Stackoverflow and others don't seem to work like this. It seems that the software should not be promoting questions on the front page that a human would consider dead.

Comment: Maybe it's just this site, I don't know. We get the Community bot pinging all sorts of questions that haven't been touched in years, posted by users who haven't logged on in years.